# Data sending problem. (Front-end)React+TailwindCSS (Back-end)FlaskAPI

Tags: reactjs, database, flask, post, backend

The back-end part is written in Flask, and has such a hierarchy:
[image: hierarchy-photo]
I get an error sending to the data server, most likely related to the photo uploading.

app.py code:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///cars.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'uploads'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Car(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    brand = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    model = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    type = db.Column(db.String(50))
    axle = db.Column(db.String(50))
    year = db.Column(db.String(10))
    price = db.Column(db.String(20))
    color = db.Column(db.String(20))
    weight = db.Column(db.String(20))
    mileage = db.Column(db.String(20))
    photo = db.Column(db.String(100))
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

@app.route('/api/cars', methods=['GET'])
def get_cars():
    try:
        cars = Car.query.all()
        car_list = []
        for car in cars:
            car_list.append({
                'id': car.id,
                'brand': car.brand,
                'model': car.model,
                'type': car.type,
                'axle': car.axle,
                'year': car.year,
                'price': car.price,
                'color': car.color,
                'weight': car.weight,
                'mileage': car.mileage,
                'photo': car.photo,
                'description': car.description
            })
        return jsonify({'cars': car_list})

    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error(e)
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)}), 500

@app.route('/api/cars', methods=['POST'])
def add_car():
    try:
        data = request.form
        file = request.files['photo']

        
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        new_car = Car(
            brand=data['brand'],
            model=data['model'],
            type=data['type'],
            axle=data['axle'],
            year=data['year'],
            price=data['price'],
            color=data['color'],
            weight=data['weight'],
            mileage=data['mileage'],
            photo=filename,  # Сохраняем имя файла в базе данных
            description=data['description']
        )

        db.session.add(new_car)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify({"message": "Car added successfully!"})


    except Exception as e:
        app.logger.error("Error: %s", e)
        return jsonify({"error": "Internal Server Error"}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

AddCarForm.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import BrandSelection from "./AddFormComponents/BrandSelection.jsx";
import CharacteristicsForm from "./AddFormComponents/CharacteristicsForm.jsx";
import MetricValues from "./AddFormComponents/MetricValues.jsx";
import PhotoUpload from "./AddFormComponents/PhotoUpload.jsx";
import DescriptionForm from "./AddFormComponents/DescriptionForm.jsx";

const AddCarForm = () => {
    const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(1);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        brand: "",
        model: "",
        type: "",
        axle: "",
        year: "",
        price: "",
        color: "",
        weight: "",
        mileage: "",
        photo: null,
        description: ""
    });

    const handleNextStep = () => {
        setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
    }

    const handlePrevStep = () => {
        setCurrentStep(currentStep - 1);
    }

    const handleFormChange = (fieldName, value) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [fieldName]: value
        });
    }

    const handlePhotoUpload = (selectedPhotos) => {
        if (selectedPhotos.length > 0 && selectedPhotos[0].file) {
            // Объект содержит поле 'file'
            setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
                ...prevFormData,
                photo: selectedPhotos[0].file
            }));
        } else {
            console.error("Invalid selectedPhotos format");
        }
    }


    const handleSubmit = async () => {
        try {
            const formDataObj = new FormData();
            Object.entries(formData).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                formDataObj.append(key, value);
            });

            console.log("Form Data:", formDataObj);

            const response = await fetch('https://api-services-ubw8.onrender.com/api/cars', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
                body: formDataObj,
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log("Form submitted successfully!");
            } else {
                console.error('Error submitting form: ', response.statusText);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error submitting form: ', error.message);
        }
    }

    return (
        <form className="mt-10 w-3/4 md:w-2/4 bg-white/70 rounded-xl flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-center">
            <div className={`h-${currentStep * 1/4}/5 w-full p-10`}>
                {currentStep === 1 && <BrandSelection onPrevStep={handlePrevStep} onNextStep={handleNextStep} onSelectBrandAndModel={(brand, model) => handleFormChange('brand', brand, 'model', model)} />}
                {currentStep === 2 && <CharacteristicsForm onPrevStep={handlePrevStep} onNextStep={handleNextStep} onCharacteristicChange={(fieldName, value) => handleFormChange(fieldName, value)} />}
                {currentStep === 3 && <MetricValues onPrevStep={handlePrevStep} onNextStep={handleNextStep} onCharacteristicChange={(fieldName, value) => handleFormChange(fieldName, value)} />}
                {currentStep === 4 && <PhotoUpload name={"photo"} onPrevStep={handlePrevStep} onNextStep={handleNextStep} onPhotoSelect={handlePhotoUpload} />}
                {currentStep === 5 && <DescriptionForm onPrevStep={handlePrevStep} onNextStep={handleNextStep} onDescriptionChange={(value) => handleFormChange('description', value)} />}
            </div>

            {currentStep === 5 && (
                <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit} className="m-4 bg-blue-500 text-white px-20 py-2 rounded-full font-bold">
                    Add ✅
                </button>
            )}
        </form>
    );
};

export default AddCarForm;
```

I’m almost sure the problems in handleSubmit
or in handlePhotoUpload, because the error indicates rather that the data comes in the wrong format for the server.

PhotoUpload.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import ModalImage from 'react-modal-image';

const PhotoUpload = ({ selectedPhotos, onPhotoSelect, onPrevStep, onNextStep }) => {
    const [uploadedPhotos, setUploadedPhotos] = useState([]);
    const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

    const onDrop = (acceptedFiles) => {
        const selectedImages = acceptedFiles.map((file) => ({ name: file.name, file }));
        setUploadedPhotos(selectedImages);
        onPhotoSelect(selectedImages);
    };

    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

    const openModal = (image) => {
        setSelectedImage(image);
    };

    const closeModal = () => {
        setSelectedImage(null);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className="text-xl md:text-2xl">Photos Uploading</h2>
            <div
                {...getRootProps()}
                className={`dropzone border-dashed border ${isDragActive ? 'border-green-500' : 'border-gray-300'} rounded-md p-4 text-center cursor-pointer`}
            >
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                <p>{isDragActive ? 'Drop the photos here' : 'Drag and drop photos here or click to browse.'}</p>
            </div>
            {/* Отображение выбранных и загруженных фотографий */}
            {uploadedPhotos.length > 0 && (
                <div>
                    <h3>Выбранные фотографии:</h3>
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-5 gap-4">
                        {uploadedPhotos.map((photo, index) => (
                            <img
                                key={index}
                                src={URL.createObjectURL(photo.file)}
                                alt={photo.name}
                                className="max-w-full h-auto rounded cursor-pointer"
                                onClick={() => openModal(photo)}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
            {selectedPhotos && selectedPhotos.length > 0 && (
                <div>
                    <h3>Загруженные фотографии:</h3>
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 xl:grid-cols-5 gap-4">
                        {selectedPhotos.map((photo, index) => (
                            <img
                                key={index}
                                src={URL.createObjectURL(photo.file)}
                                alt={photo.name}
                                className="max-w-full h-auto rounded cursor-pointer"
                                onClick={() => openModal(photo)}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

            {/* Модальное окно для увеличения изображения */}
            {selectedImage && (
                <div
                    className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-black bg-opacity-75 flex items-center justify-center">
                    <div className="max-w-md w-full bg-white rounded-lg px-4 pb-2">
                        <button className="text-3xl" onClick={closeModal}>
                            Close❌
                        </button>
                        <ModalImage
                            small={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage.file)}
                            large={URL.createObjectURL(selectedImage.file)}
                            alt={selectedImage.name}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}

            <div className={"flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between w-full mt-10"}>
                <button onClick={onPrevStep}
                        className={"m-2 bg-blue-500 w-full md:w-1/4 h-10 text-white rounded-xl font-semibold"}>Previous
                    Step
                </button>

                <button onClick={onNextStep}
                        className={"m-2 bg-blue-500 w-full md:w-1/4 h-10 text-white rounded-xl font-semibold"}>Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PhotoUpload;
```

Server Logs:

```
==> Using Node version 20.10.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Running 'gunicorn app:app'
[2024-02-22 20:16:21 +0000] [41] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2024-02-22 20:16:21 +0000] [41] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:10000 (41)
[2024-02-22 20:16:21 +0000] [41] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-02-22 20:16:21 +0000] [42] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 42
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2024:20:16:28 +0000] "GET /api/cars HTTP/1.1" 200 643 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/render/project/src/app.py", line 65, in add_car
    file = request.files['photo']
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures/structures.py", line 192, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 1110, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 953, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 687, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py", line 377, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
          ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 236, in run
    super().run()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 571, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 642, in spawn_workers
    self.spawn_worker()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 609, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 142, in init_process
    self.run()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_for_one(timeout)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 70, in run_for_one
    self.accept(listener)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 32, in accept
    self.handle(listener, client, addr)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 178, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1488, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/opt/render/project/src/app.py", line 94, in add_car
    app.logger.error("Error:", e)
Message: 'Error:'
Arguments: (<BadRequestKeyError '400: Bad Request'>,)
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Feb/2024:20:16:45 +0000] "POST /api/cars HTTP/1.1" 500 34 "http://localhost:5173/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Client errors:

[image]
[image]

To the server I send, as you can see, in form-data format and view of course in JSON:

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "axle": "Back",
      "brand": "Lexus",
      "color": "Silver",
      "description": "Features 2.5L V-6 Engine. 6-spd man w/OD Transmission. 204 @ 6,400 rpm Horsepower.",
      "id": 1,
      "mileage": "245300",
      "model": "IS",
      "photo": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Lexus_IS250_silver.jpg",
      "price": "5600",
      "type": "Sedan",
      "weight": "1600",
      "year": "2007"
    },
    {
      "axle": "Back",
      "brand": "Lexus",
      "color": "Silver",
      "description": "Features 2.5L V-6 Engine. 6-spd man w/OD Transmission. 204 @ 6,400 rpm Horsepower.",
      "id": 2,
      "mileage": "234000",
      "model": "IS",
      "photo": "1200px-Lexus_IS250_2008_Tungsten_Pearl.jpg",
      "price": "5600",
      "type": "Sedan",
      "weight": "1600",
      "year": "2007"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I send with the Postman program, everything is fine, not with the client, it follows that the problem is not on the server side, but rather in the file with the form for sending.

[image: postman-screenshot1]
[image: postman-screenshot2]

Please help me to implement correct data sending from client to server.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem"; a series of tag words is rarely a good summary. also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: yeah this post is very long, it would be better if you could try to isolate/pin down the problem and give a more concise question. Ideally create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)